# Jquery keypress event on textbox in page loaded by ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have main page `index.php` and on this page onbutton click I am loadin url.php using ajax.

In url.php I have `text box`. I want when user take courser in this texbox to enter something, the button below it show become visible.

url.php

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="sent" contenteditable="true"  style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:512px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..."/></input>
<button id="b1" style="display:none" > Get Sentiment </button>
```

index.php

In body part:

```
<script>
    $("#text").keypress( function() {
        document.getElementById("b1").style.display = "block";
        console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
    });
</script>
```

But text box does not appear on when I go to text box and click in it. I also tried with 
`blur` and `focus` in place of `keypress` but no change.

To load url.php using ajax I have folowing code:

```
<input type="button" id="load_url" value="Load url.php" />
$("#load_url").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"url.php",
        success:function(response) {
            $("#view_port").html(response);
            $("#load_url").hide();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Register the `keypress` event after you load the url.php using ajax.

Comment: Enclose the `keypress` inside a function and call that inside the success part.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `url.php` to:

```
<textarea id="text" name="sent" contenteditable="true" style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:512px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..."></textarea>
<input type="button" id="b1" style="display:none" value=" Get Sentiment" />
```

OR

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="sent" contenteditable="true" style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:512px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..." />
<input type="button" id="b1" style="display:none" value=" Get Sentiment" />
```

and Use

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#text").bind("keypress", function( e ) {...});
});
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thanks but `<button>` I have taken is must for me. There is some specific css style requirement for me so it's customized css button.

Comment: Can't you use `class="btn"` in `<input type="button" id="b1" class="btn" />`? And then stylize it using 
`.btn{
display:none;
//other CSS rules
}` in your `<head><style type="text/css"></style></head>`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#text").keypress( function() {
        $("#b1").show();
        console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to change the id `text` to `textabc` and bind in jquery and then try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to register the `keypress` event after the AJAX load.

```
    $( document ).ready( function(e) {
       $('#button').click(function(e) { // Clicking the button to load the url.php
          $('#somediv').load("url.php", function() { // loading the url.php
             $('#text').keypress(function(e) { // You are registering the keypress event listener after the ajax load
                 $('#b1').show('fast');
             });
          }
       });
   });
```

Comment: to load url.php I already have code check my updated question!